# reliable session wcf - how is acknowledgement guaranteed?

Tags: c#, wcf

How does destination ensure that acknowledgement is sent back to source in case of reliable sessions, e.g. following article states that

http://www.request-response.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,a6cb59e6-cbc2-4ce3-92b2-ea40bc5929f6.aspx

"concepts which enable the developer to insist on reliably delivering messages in **both directions.** The mechanism is actually transport agnostic and allows messages to be flown reliably from client to service and **replies from service to client**"

I can understand - in case of a network issue say ISP peering issue, in case the message is not delivered - Source itself can raise an exception but how does destination notify the source that message was received in case of a network issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got all the relevant details from following link, everything is explained in detail.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx